# Issue with MSAL: Application [ClientID] is not supported for this API version

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

Trying to use MSAL to log into my Azure app, and I'm getting the following:

```
Additional technical information:
Correlation ID: 4a3f4692-a698-4e89-ba29-3146d9b92d7b
Timestamp: 2017-08-09 16:50:57Z
AADSTS70001: Application 'ClientID GUID' is not supported for this API version.
```

Can someone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error means that you've registered an Azure AD v1.0 application, but are hitting the Azure AD v2.0 converged endpoint.

[Here's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-compare) a nice explanation of the differences between the two, but in short v1 can sign in Azure AD users whereas the v2.0 converged endpoint can sign in Azure AD and Microsoft Account users. The v2.0 endpoint currently supports a subset of functionality, so depending on your scenario you may choose to stick with v1. The [v2 limitations doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-limitations) should help figure out if v2.0 is right for you.

***v1.0***

- Apps registered in https://portal.azure.com
- Use the [ADAL libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-libraries).
- Supports more scenarios at this point in time.
- Supports Azure AD accounts.

***v2.0***

- Apps registered in https://apps.dev.microsoft.com
- Use the [MSAL libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-libraries)
- Compatible with most open source libraries.
- Supports Azure AD and Microsoft Accounts (outlook, hotmail, live, etc).

Comment: OMG! That explains it. I created my app through apps.dev.microsoft.com. :) Thanks for the excellent explanation.